# How can I insert audio into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Insert Into [dbo].[Letterland] ([letter],[letterImage])
   Select 'a', BulkColumn,
   From Openrowset (bulk 'H:\Data\D\ll-image\annie.png', Single_blob) as img 

Insert Into [dbo].[Letterland] ([letterDescAudio])
    Select 'a', BulkColumn, BulkColumn
   From Openrowset (bulk 'H:\Data\D\11-image\aa.wav' Single_blob) as img 

Insert Into [dbo].[Letterland] ([letterSound])
    Select 'a', BulkColumn, BulkColumn
   From Openrowset (bulk 'H:\Data\D\ll-image\a.wav', Single_blob) as img
```

This is what I tried but I know that it is incorrect. I am trying to insert the data as a single row.

```
[dbo].[Letterland] ([Letter], [letterImage], [letterDescAudio],  [letterSound])
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be. SQL Server (or any SQL database) is no replacement for a file system and isn't designed to handle large amounts of binary data efficiently. Store it in a file and keep a file reference in the database.

Comment: Hey Ron Beyer, my data is stored in different files and not on sql server as per say. I however am having trouble referencing all the data in a single row insert.

Comment: Does what you are trying to do work in SQL management studio? You didn't post any C# code so I can't say that your problem is in the coding. It also looks like you are trying to insert wav data as an image?

Comment: Can you tell us the data types of the columns? Also, what is the error you get when you try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to load your three blobs first, into variables, and then do a *single* `INSERT` to insert them all into your table - something like this:

```
-- declare a VARBINARY(MAX) variable to hold the "image"
DECLARE @Image VARBINARY(MAX)

-- load the "image"
SELECT @Image = BulkColumn,
FROM Openrowset (bulk 'H:\Data\D\ll-image\annie.png', Single_blob) as img 

-- declare a VARBINARY(MAX) variable to hold the "Desc Audio" and load it
DECLARE @DescAudio VARBINARY(MAX)

SELECT @DescAudio = BulkColumn
FROM Openrowset (bulk 'H:\Data\D\11-image\aa.wav' Single_blob) as img 

-- declare a VARBINARY(MAX) variable to hold the "Sound" and load it
DECLARE @Sound VARBINARY(MAX)

SELECT @Sound = BulkColumn
FROM Openrowset (bulk 'H:\Data\D\ll-image\a.wav', Single_blob) as img 

-- now do the INSERT with all bits ready to go    
INSERT INTO dbo.Letterland (letter, letterImage, letterDescAudio, letterSound)
VALUES ('a', @Image, @DescAudio, @Sound)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is save the file path to the database. Say your audio file is in path '~/audio/1.mp3'. So you can insert it in the database table as:

```
string audio = <your path to audio>;
INSERT INTO [TABLE NAME] VALUES(audio);
```